# netbeans build project error

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

i am new in java and i am a student, I am using net beans 8.0 for java developing i created a project and run it using Shift+F6, it is working fine, but when i go for build project from the project categories then in the "Browse Java FX Application Classes" window nothing display in "available classes" so therefore i can't build my project. Moreover the dist folder also not exist in my project.

Please let me know how to resolve this problem where i am wrong or which option i miss.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to find the class that `extends Application`.  You can right click the project in the project window the choose properties then run.  You will see a box for Application class.  You should be able to select the class there.

If there's nothing in the 'select classes' box then maybe you forgot to declare the class like

```
public class JavaFXApp extends Application {
    //etc..
```